# Загрузка данных в модель и валидация - различие в двух способах

Tags: yii2

При передаче на страницу get параметра, мне нужно загрузить данные из БД и заполнить ими форму. Но какой из двух способов использовать предпочтительнее для этого и почему:

```
$data=[...]; //массив данных, который получен из бд;
$peopleModel->load($data); //Вариант 1
$peopleModel->attributes = $data; //Вариант 2

return $this->render('registration', compact('peopleModel'));
```

Comment: Никогда не углублялся в этот вопрос и думаю что если разница и есть, то очень незначительная. Сам всегда использую load() и никогда не имел с ним проблем.

Comment: http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/9091  ..... хотя говорят, что если писать так `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->get(), '');` то будет производиться поиск не в подмассиве а просто в массиве типа `$_POST['username'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница двух способов загрузки данных в модель лишь в том, что если вы используете конструкцию типа `$model->load($_GET)` то в `$model` будут загружены все данные из массива `$_GET[$model->formName()]` ([подробнее](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/3bd813339ed0aeac8baac35eef55eac7d2881d9c/framework/base/Model.php#L819)), в то время как при использовании конструкции `$model->setAttributes($_GET)` в `$model` будут загружены все данные из массива `$_GET` ([подробнее](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/3bd813339ed0aeac8baac35eef55eac7d2881d9c/framework/base/Model.php#L692)).